# Indexes by solr occupying a lot of space

Tags: solr, lucene

I am indexing around 20 gb of data using solr 4.4.0 . After indexing I am getting  20 gb of data which is beyond the space size i have . I am not using omitNorms="true" as yet but i read that mergefactor can really help to decrease the size of indexes without hampering the performance but I couldn't understand how ..
Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing fields, you might think of [compressing](http://solr.pl/en/2012/11/19/solr-4-1-stored-fields-compression/) them. Compressing is supported at Lucene level and [performs rather well](http://blog.jpountz.net/post/35667727458/stored-fields-compression-in-lucene-4-1).

Comment: I thought of using them. but solr 4.4 does not support compression .

Comment: Any proof? [This](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201308.mbox/%3C51FA75EB.7090201@elyograg.org%3E) suggests otherwise.

Comment: I meant hardcoding as in writing compression="true" in schema.xml does not work as it is present by default. So what else i can do to decrease te size of my indexes ?

Comment: And how can we estimate the index size if we are indexing say 15GB worth of plain text files? With the file's content also stored as part of index stored fields.

Comment: Estimation is explained [here](https://lucidworks.com/blog/estimating-memory-and-storage-for-lucenesolr/).

Comment: By using analyzer component in my schema in the FieldType I am able to decrease the size from 21 gb to 7 gb . Suggest some other way as well .